# Execution time difference while returning vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I was solving a question where I was supposed to complete a given function which was as follows:

```
vector<string> funcName(Parameter p1)
```

I tried two submissions, with a small change in the way the function returns.
**Submission 1: 8ms**

```
vector<string> funcName(Parameter p1){
    vector<string> x;
    if(some condition)
       return x;
   // Other code logic
}
```

**Submission 2: 0ms**

```
vector<string> funcName(Parameter p1){
    vector<string> x;
    if(some condition)
       return {};
   // Other code logic
}
```

The vector is being allocated space in both the cases.
Why does this time difference exist?

**EDIT 1**

**Submission 1: 8ms**

```
vector<string> binaryTreePaths(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<string> ans;
        map<TreeNode*,string> mapper;
        if(root==nullptr)
            return ans;
        queue<TreeNode*> q;
        q.push(root);
        mapper[root] = to_string(root->val);
        while(!q.empty()){
            TreeNode* curr = q.front();
            if(curr->left!=nullptr){
                mapper[curr->left] = mapper[curr] + "->" + to_string(curr->left->val);
                q.push(curr->left);
            }
            if(curr->right!=nullptr){
                mapper[curr->right] = mapper[curr] + "->" + to_string(curr->right->val);
                q.push(curr->right);
            }
            if(curr->left==nullptr && curr->right==nullptr)
                ans.push_back(mapper[curr]);

            q.pop();
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

**Submission 2: 0ms**

```
vector<string> binaryTreePaths(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<string> ans;
        map<TreeNode*,string> mapper;
        if(root==nullptr)
            return {};
        queue<TreeNode*> q;
        q.push(root);
        mapper[root] = to_string(root->val);
        while(!q.empty()){
            TreeNode* curr = q.front();
            if(curr->left!=nullptr){
                mapper[curr->left] = mapper[curr] + "->" + to_string(curr->left->val);
                q.push(curr->left);
            }
            if(curr->right!=nullptr){
                mapper[curr->right] = mapper[curr] + "->" + to_string(curr->right->val);
                q.push(curr->right);
            }
            if(curr->left==nullptr && curr->right==nullptr)
                ans.push_back(mapper[curr]);

            q.pop();
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: 8ms is not a lot of time.  That could easily be margin of error. Run the function a few hundred thousand times and get an average of all the runs.  They should be the same then.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX, the only difference between the two code snippets is the way of  returning inside the if condition.

Comment: The compiler has a lot of leeway with the "as if" rule. In the second case, it could have moved the vector construction after the branch. Although Nathan is right. And make sure you have full optimizations enabled when benchmarking - microbenchmarks are actually really hard to do well in C++

Comment: @T.Square thanks. I looked it up. Never saw this type of returning

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica thanks :)

Comment: @Mat thanks :), will try running it multiple times.

Comment: I'm rather surprised second variant is faster; assuming you `return x;` after completing `other logic`, too, I'd have expected either both being the same or, as returning two different objects then, even second variant being slower due to NRVO possibly failing...

Comment: [This](https://www.godbolt.org/z/d5z_Vn)  is interesting, there is much more code generated for the second version. In the second case the return value is constructed explicitely, which results in more code being executed, so it should be slower. I'm sure your mesuring method is flawed. How do you mesure?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Don't forget to turn on optimizations.  They cut out a lot of the code and only make it a 2 line difference.  Looks like that is a GCC optimization bug since clang gives basically the same code: https://www.godbolt.org/z/htx-MX

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am submitting it on leetcode, where it is being run on their testcases.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica the point is compiling non optimized. Optimized gcc and clang basically optimize away both of the code.

Comment: @T.Square we need to see your _actual_ code. Otherwise we can't really draw any valid conclusions

Comment: @Jabberwocky There is no point inspecting un-optimized code (unless debugging).  There is too much debugging stuff going on in un-optimized code to give them a fair comparison.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have added the entire code for both the submissions.

Comment: Thank you for posting the larger sample, it gives a much better picture. Are you able to share the `TreeNode` struct as well?